# Error accessing aerospike C client through Cgo

Tags: c, go, makefile, cgo, gccgo

I am trying to learn Cgo, so i tried accessing aerospike client from Cgo

```
package main  
// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <string.h>
// #include "aerospike-client-c/examples/put/example_utils.h"
import "C"
import (
"unsafe"
)
func main() {  
   retvals := C.putitnew()
  _=retvals
}
```

But i get below errors. ( Please note the C program runs successfully when i do make and make run ).

```
undefined reference to `example_get_opts'
./aerospike-client-c/examples/put/example.c:66: undefined reference to 
`example_connect_to_aerospike'
./aerospike-client-c/examples/put/example.c:69: undefined reference to 
`example_remove_test_record'
./aerospike-client-c/examples/put/example.c:78: undefined reference to 
  `as_record_init'
./aerospike-client-c/examples/put/example.c:79: undefined reference to 
`as_record_set_int64'
/tmp/go-build283334635/b046/_x002.o: In function `as_record_set_str':
....
```

So i believe the issue is with the configuration in Makefile. I have searched for entire day and tried many solutions but invain. Can you help me how i could import Makefile in Cgo?  Or an alternative to help me execute this successfully..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with the relevant library.  I believe the library is called `-laerospike`.  In this case, the `cgo` directive would look like this:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -laerospike
```

See [the cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Furthermore, you need to link in the relevant example code.  I don't see a `put` example in the official repository.  You will likely have to copy part of its sources directly in the `cgo` section of your Go file because examples are usually not intended for direct linking.